# How do I move a window across screens using the same keyboard shortcut for "half-screen"?

Tags: gnome-shell, window, window-manager

In my current setup when I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> the window I'm on snaps to the left, but let's say I want to move it across my current screen to jump another screen to the left, if I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> again, nothing happens, it just stays snapped to the left.

I know I can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> as well to move it across, but I want it to act the same as on Windows, one press to the left snaps it to the left, the next press -> moves it across to the other screen.

I've tried installing `compiz-config` but haven't been able to find the option I'm looking for there.

I'm running on:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- GNOME Shell 3.36.4

Comment: For this question it's really important **which flavor** of Ubuntu you are using, **the version** of it and the **Desktop Environment** (Gnome or other?). [Edit your answer](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1316565/edit) and add these details please.